# meta query multiple values for the same key

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I'm trying to query wordpress with multiple values but it looks like it can't take no more than 4 keywords

I'm currently using a loop and I already tried to switch to a **IN** operator but I need the query to work with wildcards and while **REGEXP** does the job, IN does not

```
foreach ($keywords as $value) {
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'customfields',
            'value' => $value,
            'compare' => 'REGEXP'  
        )
    );
}
```

In this case `$keywords` is an array of words that I need to query to a custom field. It works with a few keywords, but it breaks with 5 or more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing an array of values to the `value` argument?

```
$your_terms = array( 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' );

$args['meta_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'customfields',
        'value' => $your_terms,
        'compare' => 'REGEXP'  
    )
);

$this_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Did you mean to delete foreach loop aswell? Anyway this just doesn't work...

Comment: What does "this just doesn't work" mean?  WP_Query does not require a loop to iterate numerous queries that can be accomplished with a single, properly constructed one.

Comment: I don't get any result by doing so, my code gets the desired results instead, mine just doesn't work with more than 4 keywords (more than 4 iteration)

Answer (score 0):

In its current form, your `meta_query` is **overwritten** in each iteration. In the final effect, you have only one custom field in `meta_query`:

Depending on the operator you want to use, `meta_query` argument should look as follow:

- for "**LIKE**", "**REGEXP**"

  ```
  if( is_array($keywords) && count($keywords) ) {

      $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );
      foreach( $keywords as $value )
      {
          $args['meta_query'][] = array(
              'key' => 'customfields',
              'value' => $value,
              'compare' => 'REGEXP', // or 'LIKE'
          );
      }
  }
  //  === result: ===
  // $args['meta_query'] = array( 
  //     'relation' => 'OR',
  //     [ 'key' => 'customfields', 'value' => 'value_1', 'compare' => 'REGEXP' ],
  //     [ 'key' => 'customfields', 'value' => 'value_2', 'compare' => 'REGEXP' ],
  //     [ 'key' => 'customfields', 'value' => 'value_3', 'compare' => 'REGEXP' ],
  // );
  ```
- for "**IN**"

  ```
  if( is_array($keywords) && count($keywords) ) {

      $args['meta_query'] = array( 
          'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
              'key' => 'customfields',
              'value' => $keywords,
              'compare' => 'IN',
          )
      );
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks for helping: while the IN query does not return any results (maybe IN operator hasn't %wildcards% for words inside the array?), the first one works just fine as the one I posted but, like mine, if the array is equal or greater than 5 words it takes a lot for the page to load (minutes).

Comment: `IN` looks for the exact match. The meta query is expensive, especially when using `LIKE`, that's why it's slow.

Comment: so what's a possible solution to this? how can I query for more than 4 terms without going that slow?

Comment: [Slow meta query with multi meta keys](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/276315/147428)